# How to nest array inside of hash initizer?

Tags: perl

In Perl, Is possible to nest an array inside of a hash initializer all as one statement?  And how to address and access the nested Array inside of a hash later?  I know how to do this by breaking it up into separate statement... how to do it with only one initializer of the hash?  Example:

Pseudo code:

```
%hash = {
     Param1 => "value1",
     Param2 => "value2",
     ParamArray => @(
         "Array1",
         "Array2",
     )
}

# Also, is how I would deref the nested array?
@Array1 = @{$hash{ParamArray}};
```

Comment: See also [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut).

Answer (score 2):

Hash values can only be scalars, not arrays. The trick is to use a reference to an array.

```
my @array = ( "Array1", "Array2" );

my %hash = (
   Param1     => "value1",
   Param2     => "value2",
   ParamArray => \@array,
);
```

You can create an anonymous array using `[]`. It returns a reference to the array. The following is therefore equivalent to the above:

```
my %hash = (
   Param1     => "value1",
   Param2     => "value2",
   ParamArray => [ "Array1", "Array2" ],
);
```

In either case, you can use

```
say for @{ $hash{$ParamArray} };
```

I wouldn't use the following as it needlessly makes a copy of the array:

```
my @array = @{$hash{ParamArray}};
say $array[0];
```

Instead, I'd work with a reference to the array.

```
my $array_ref = $hash{ParamArray};
say $array_ref->[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an array ref:

```
$hash = {
    Param1 => "value1",
    Param2 => "value2",
    ParamArray => [
        "Array1",
        "Array2",
    ]
}
```

The square brackets are syntax to make an array ref literal. Also you need to use the scalar sigil for hash since `{}` makes a ref as well. In order to access the element you need to deref the hash and the nested array, like so:

```
 @{$hash->{ParamArray}}
```

EDIT:

Didn't notice the hash ref.